# Can't grab wp recent posts topic Sql error

Tags: php, wordpress

The error is

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'lekalic'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/lekalic/public_html/latest_new.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/lekalic/public_html/latest_new.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/lekalic/public_html/latest_new.php on line 12

Comment: It is authentication error. Check if password and user for database is correct.

Comment: Which folder should i check load.php or which one?

Comment: Show how you try to retrieve posts, where you make connection to database.

Comment: <?php
     include_once 'wp-config.php';
        $number = 14 ;
        $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $number"); 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
     $id = $row["ID"];
     $title = $row["post_title"];
     $content = $row["post_content"];
     ?>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><a href="http://www.lekali.com/?p=<?php print "$id";?>" target="_blank"><?php print "$title"; ?></a></td>
 </table>
<?php
}
?>

Comment: You aren't selecting any database, you aren't pointing to anything. Where do you specify which database you are calling in `mysql_query()`?

Comment: and in wp-config.php i have /** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'mydbnames');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mydbpasswords');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

Comment: So how to do it can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to database before you retrieve any data:

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("databasename",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select examples");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $number");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //do stuff
}

mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

Comment: I have put as your code now error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/lekalic/public_html/latest_new.php on line 25

Comment: Can you http://pastebin.com/ your latest_new.php (make sure you remove password etc for your database)

Comment: hello sorry for late reply again here is the problem Could not select examples http://lekali.com/latest_new.php

Comment: Hello Kami again have error could not select examples please help thank you